# Varnish 503 but Apache response is 200 OK

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

Apache2 have this log:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Aug/2021:19:17:10 +0200] "GET /index.php?id_product=35&controller=product HTTP/1.1" 200 87103 "https://DOMINIO.it/catalog/products/359" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.164 Safari/537.36"
```

But Varnish response is 503.

I have this error on all Prestashop frontend page and on some admin page, a test page with phpinfo.php or static html works correctly.

I do this settings:
default.vcl

```
backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8080";
    .first_byte_timeout = 600s;
    .connect_timeout = 600s;
    .between_bytes_timeout = 600s;
}
```

In start service:

```
DAEMON_OPTS="-a :80 \
             -a 127.0.0.1:8443,proxy \
             -T localhost:6082 \
             -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl \
             -S /etc/varnish/secret \
             -p thread_pools=2 \
             -p thread_pool_max=600 \
             -p listen_depth=1024 \
             -p lru_interval=900 \
             -p connect_timeout=600 \
             -p max_restarts=6 \
             -s malloc,1G"
```

Someone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Please attach some `varnishlog` output for these requests.

Here's the command you need:

```
varnishlog -g request -q "ReqUrl eq '/catalog/products/359'"
```

> My assumption is that the request URL is `/catalog/products/359`. Please change the URL in the `varnishlog` command if that is not the correct URL.

Please also share some `varnishstat` output from the moment the problem occurs. This is the command you need:

```
varnishstat -1
```

This command will dump the current counters. There might be some interesting things going on that stats & logs will expose.